# Were we ever meant to write SQL queries off of a Sharepoint list?

Tags: sql, sharepoint

I've read excerpts stating that we shouldn't write SQL off Sharepoint lists but they don't really explain why. Is it because of the obfuscation of field names as generic data types? Or is it because Sharepoint lists don't have Keys, either PK or FK associated with them?

Comment: You should use the Sharepoint API to query lists.  And the reason you shouldn't directly query via SQL is because a Sharepoint update could break your query if that update involves a structural or schema change

Comment: Let's expand on the Sharepoint update part. For example if I delete or add columns to it?

Comment: No.  If the Sharepoint developers make a change...they could very well rename something or change its data type or rework its structure.  The API would get updated to account for those changes and your query against the API shouldn't break.  However, your query against the SQL tables might.

Comment: Some other reasons are discussed [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42787/Five-Reasons-Not-to-Directly-Query-SharePoint-Data#:~:text=Directly%20querying%20the%20database%20can,deadlocks%20and%20hence%20stability%20issues.)

Comment: thank you! this answers everything!!!